# ABNewPersonViewController change backgroundColor

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Is it possible to change ABNewPersonViewController background color instead of default 
grey-stripe background? How?

Comment: have you tried logging the subviews? you could locate the backgroundView(probably a UIImageView) and alter the image there. This is a rather dirty approach, but the only one I can think of in these situations, as ABPersonViewController doesnt expose any interface to alter its looks.

Answer (score 0):

It helped me on IOS7

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor: [UIColor whiteColor]]
```